# C# UDP socket app to listen to messages from various sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I have a system monitor app that needs to listen to messages from various UDP sockets on another machine. The other sockets continuously send heartbeats to this given IP/port.

This exception gets thrown when calling BeginReceiveFrom:
"A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

I shouldn't have to call connect because data is already getting sent to this ip endpoint. plus the data is coming from various sockets.

```
    private Socket m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // bind socket
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
        // host running the application.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        m_localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 19018);
        m_socket.Bind(m_localEndPoint);

        m_socket.BeginReceiveFrom(m_data, 
                                  m_nBytes, 
                                  MAX_READ_SIZE, 
                                  SocketFlags.None,
                                  ref m_localEndPoint, 
                                  new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                  null);

    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
            int nRead = m_socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref m_localEndPoint);
     }
```

Comment: Are you running it as the administrator user, firewall off? Windows will block binding on "various ports"

Comment: I'm not binding the socket to various ports, I'm binding it to one port. It is receiving data from various UDP sockets on another machine. I'm running the app on a windows xp machine under an administrator account.

Comment: Why are you using `BeginReceiveFrom` instead of `BeginReceive`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behavior with the UdpClient class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was you were binding to the IP assigned to you, you should bind to IP you want receive from - in your case:

```
m_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
```