# UDP Listener c#

Tags: asp.net, udp

I asked a query this morning, here is the link - [thread interrupt in udp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832574/thread-interrupt-in-udp-in-c-sharp)

but after spending some more hours on this issue - I have concluded that what I need to do is -

I need to create a udp server whose job is to listen and receive data from port 1200. 
and I need to create another udp socket to send data using any other port.

I want this udp listener to listen continuously as a background process. 
so I  tried to do that but I am getting this error - and more over the statement is saying when sending data using sendto method even I am not sending any data here.

> "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"
>
> ```
>   StackTrace  "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_RemoteEndPoint()"  string
>   SocketErrorCode NotConnected    System.Net.Sockets.SocketError
> ```

I used this code for receiving on port 1200 with any remote client-

```
  public void button1_Click()
    {
        this.serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        this.serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        this.serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.port));
        EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        this.serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.byteData, 0, this.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, serverSocket);

    }

    private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
    {


        try
        {
            EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            int dataLen = 0;
            byte[] data = null;
            try
            {
                dataLen = this.serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
                data = new byte[dataLen];
                Array.Copy(this.byteData, data, dataLen);
                string ips = ((IPEndPoint)clientEP).Address.ToString();
                server sss = new server();
                sss.updateData(data, ips);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                this.serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.byteData, 0, this.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, serverSocket);
            }

            if (!this.clientList.Any(client => client.Equals(clientEP)))
                this.clientList.Add(clientEP);



            string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string m = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.serverSocket.Close();
        this.serverSocket = null;
        this.clientList.Clear();
    }
```

what should I do now? MY problem is this now - 
I just want to get whatever and whenever 1200 receives data and find the remote ip from that and then do some task . I have had examples for doing something like this but they are on TCP and TCP connects to each device but UDP does not.

So how can I do with udp.?

Here is the code updated -

```
  static void OnUdpData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // this is what had been passed into BeginReceive as the second parameter:
        UdpClient socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
        // points towards whoever had sent the message:
        IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
        // get the actual message and fill out the source:
        byte[] message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref source);
        string ip = source.Address.ToString();
        server cs = new server();
        cs.updateData(message, ip);

        socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpData), socket);
    }
    public static void ReceiveData()
    {
        UdpClient socket = new UdpClient(1200); 
        socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpData), socket);


    }
```

this is working with console app but not in web form. Its throwing error as Socket can be used 1 time.

So I changed a bit more lines like this -

```
public static void ReceiveData()
    {
        IPEndPoint iPEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1200);
        UdpClient socket = new UdpClient(iPEnd);
        EndPoint ep = iPEnd;
        socket.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
        socket.Client.Bind(ep);
        socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpData), socket);
    }
```

but this is also giving error. So why is this happening?
If the code can work in console app then why not in web form?

Comment: In which line of code does the exception occur? Have you checked if any earlier exceptions have occurred and are discarded by your own exception handlers?

Comment: yes... I did some more investigation and I think I  know where did i do the mistake. I needed to send data atleast once to open the socket which I did not do. So I am editing my code now and will inform further if I am getting or not the required result.

Comment: That's great. Please share your findings with everyone by answering your own question. Others will be grateful to you.

Comment: By the way, I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307666/c-sharp-udp-socket-app-to-listen-to-messages-from-various-sockets); the answers suggest `UdpClient` will suit your needs better than `Socket`.

Comment: yes, I have seen this thread earlier but didnt got the point. But now I will try it with UdpClient first and let you know in some time.

Comment: hi, I updated the code above. The code is perfectly working in console app. Its throwing exception in web page.

Comment: Could be a permission issue (web applications run under different credentials, typically less privileged). Hard to tell; please provide full error messages. But I was wondering, why would you want to run a listening service as a web application? This feels so wrong.

Comment: It's a multimedia control device which can control projector, screen computer Nd all. I am creating a web app and need a same control page like that device with All buttons and commands. So when user click on any button in control page it should send signal to the machine and machine should do that. And vice versa. When any button pressed on machine it should also be indicated on web control page. And continuous monitor is required because there are alarm options too. Machine sends UDP packets automatically every 30 seconds if we don't do anything then also.

Comment: So suppose user is doing something else but it's a alarm time so I need that to capture in back end and send the alert. So its a continue process till the application life cycle is on

Comment: I will paste the complete error in some time. And I might have a theory for the error. Its specially when I am refreshing page. So I think when ever page is refreshed I should dispose the socket and assign resources again. Then I think it won't give only one socket use error. I will try that too.. and let you know. Tha k you so much for helping me..

Comment: So now the problem's completely changed. At the end it felt like its not possible with udp to do what i want. So they are going to change the device protocol to TCP means all cmmunication will be done using tcp. So I will use TCP from now on to work with this device.

Comment: I know this thread didnt reach to a solution and I am really feeling bad for that for other people's future reference. But the method changed so can not help it. But if anyone finds a perfect solution for this using UDP then please do share a link here.

Comment: I like the idea of a web-based multimedia control device, but please be aware that a web application is not a desktop application. A web application is not a continuously running process; it's all [client pull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology). Since you want events on the device to be reflected in the web UI, you'll have to implement [server push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) too. Explaining this in detail is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: thank you so much @ Ruud Helderman. I am trying my best but it just seems not possible for now. I dont know if I will reach to any solution or not but let's see. I am trying using websockets for now to achieve this. I will let know on this portal whatever the results will be.